# Why does x = x * y / z give a different result from x *= y / z for integers?

Tags: rust, operator-precedence, integer-division, associativity

I have the following function:

```rust
pub fn s_v1(n: &u64) -> u64 {
    let mut x: u64 = 1;

    for i in 1..=*n  {
        x = x * (*n + i) / i;
    }

    x
}
```

This code gives the correct answer for `s_v1(&20) == 137846528820`

However, if I change the line in the for loop to `x *= (*n + i) / i;`

The answer changes to `s_v1(&20) == 16094453760`

Why are the results different? Isn't `x = x * y` the same as `x *= y` ?

Comment: `x = x * y` is the same as `x *= y` but your expressions do not have this form. There is a division in there. `x = x * y / z` is not the same as `x *= y / z`. The order of operations is different

Comment: If `/` is integer division, then there's a difference between `a * (b /c)` and `(a * b) / c`, because of how the remainder is thrown away

Comment: @qrsngky: yes, all 3 variables involved have type `u64`, so this is integer division.   (The function arg is a `u64` by reference for no apparent reason or benefit, so `*n` dereferences it to get a u64.)

Comment: You may safely change `x = x * (*n + i) / i;` to `x *= (*n + i); x /= i;`

Comment: Note that the function appears to be calculating `nCr(2*n,n)`, the number of unordered combinations in which *n* elements may be drawn (without replacement) from a set of *2n*

Answer (score 33, accepted):

Because `*` and `/` have the same precedence with left associativity, the expression is not

```rust
x * ((*n + i) / i)
```

(which is the same as `x *= (*n + i) / i`) but

```rust
(x * (*n + i)) / i
```

Comment: Those 2 things are the same in _exact_ arithmetic, so the root cause is not (just) precedence per se but integer arithmetic.

Answer (score 11):

As others have indicated, there are two contributing factors:

1. `a*=b/c` is equivalent to `a=a*(b/c)` and *not* to `a=a*b/c` (which is implicitly `a=(a*b)/c`).
2. `/` denotes division according to the types of the operands. In this case the operands are both integers, and therefore `/` denotes integer division discarding any remainder, and therefore `(a*b)/c` is *not* the same as `a*(b/c)` (unless `b` is an exact multiple of `c`).

If you want to replace the line in the loop, you'd need to split the two operations:

```
    for i in 1..=*n  {
        x *= *n + i;
        x /= i;
    }
```

One disadvantage of this algorithm is that it will not produce correct results when the answer should be between MAXINT/2n and MAXINT. For that, you actually need to take advantage of what you were attempting to do:

```
    for i in 1..=*n  {
        if (x % i == 0) {
            x /= i;
            x *= *n + i;
        } else if (*n % i == 0) {
            x *= *n / i + 1;
        } else {
            x *= *n + i;
            x /= i;
        }
    }
```